# why the flash message is not appear

Tags: python-3.x, flask

When i log in the flash message is not diplayed.
How can i fix it?

```
@app.route('/Login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def show_login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        resp = make_response('your email is ' + request.form['email'])
        resp.set_cookie('email_user', request.form['email'])
        session['username'] = request.form['email']
        flash("login is success", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('show_profile', username= session['username']))

    if 'username' in session:
        username = session['username']
        return redirect(url_for('show_profile', username=username))
    return render_template('inihtml.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your template file? Have you added below code in your template file? flash is just saving the message in session (behind the scene) and you can access that by function get_flashed_messages(). As you are using category as well (Success in your case), so you have to give with_categories = true.

Below code should work for you if you haven't got already in your .html file.

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for category, message in messages %}
      <li class="{{ category }}">{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```